# Why callback is used as condition in ternary operator for Material UI Dialog component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to recreate Material UI Customized Dialog component according to [this section](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/#customization) of  documentation and I can't understand why callback function `onClose` condition is used to display `IconButton` component in `DialogTitle`:

```js
<DialogTitle sx={{ m: 0, p: 2 }} {...other}>
      {children}
      {onClose ? (
        <IconButton
          aria-label="close"
          onClick={onClose}
          sx={{
            position: 'absolute',
            right: 8,
            top: 8,
            color: (theme) => theme.palette.grey[500],
          }}
        >
          <CloseIcon />
        </IconButton>
      ) : null}
    </DialogTitle>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

As far as I understand the `IconButton` is always rendered if you set up state correctly. I just wonder is there a specific reason or pattern to use `onClick` callback function inside ternary operator? I tried to remove ternary operator altogether and everything works the same.

Comment: U should not put the callback as a condition, the state should be there, and the callback should toggle it, to display or not to display. Hope I understood ur problem correctly.

Comment: Yes I understand this, but this piece of code is straight out from official docs to MUI.

Comment: Can u share the link, please?

Comment: It was mentioned on the post, but here it is again: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/#customization

Comment: Well, it is kind of weird :D but makes sense, if no callback passed, no button, where the callback can be triggered from.

Comment: Yes, really weird syntax indeed:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the button loses all its purpose if there is no onClose function, I mean its whole point is to run that callback. So if there is no callback then don't display the button.

Comment: Yes, I think this is as simple as it is. Thank you!